# How can I make proxy setting while using Mule ESB behind a corporate wall?

Tags: proxy, mule, esb

I am very new to Mule ESB and I tried to implement a tutorial from a website:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3START/Intermediate+Studio+Tutorial

it returns connection error like this:

> Response: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en:80, connector=HttpConnector { name=HTTP_HTTPS lifecycle=start this=53edd9ee numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4 createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true connected=true supportedProtocols=[http] serviceOverrides= } , name='endpoint.http.www.google.com.tbproxy.spell.lang.en.80', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={lang=en:80, Content-Type=text/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod

Problem is probably with my proxy settings because when I do this at home there was no problem but when I try behind a corporate wall problem occurs.

There was a warning about this issue in the tutorial

So I used a connector as the warning indicated.

I typed my proxy informations as:

- proxyHostname="iproxy"
- proxyPort="8080"
- proxyUsername="ekucuk"
- proxyPassword="P34cttyb"

this is the xml line corresponding to it:

```xml
<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" proxyHostname="iproxy" proxyPort="8080" proxyUsername="ekucuk" proxyPassword="P34cttyb" doc:name="HTTP_HTTPS"/>
```

I guess the problem is in the format.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is late coming, but I just ran into the same problem and worked out a solution.

The host proxy name might need some tweaking. To find it, please look at Firefox behind the corporate firewall. Go to the Tools -> Options / Network tab and press the Settings button.

The proxy should look something like this: `http://autoproxy.mycompany.com/`. Back in the Mule IDE, you should enter `autoproxy.mycompany.com` in the Proxy Host Name field. (Strip off the http:// and the final /.)

You need to stop the Mule Spell Checker Application and then restart. (Otherwise, there is no opportunity to read the new information.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a HTTP Connector as a global element. make sure that it is a global element and comes at the top as the direct child of the mule configuration root node and not below the connectors.

```
<http:connector name="proxyConnector" proxyHostname="172.16.2.4" proxyPort="8080" proxyUsername="user" proxyPassword="password"/>
```